# Send REST API requests through Azure IoT Hub to a Raspberry Pi webserver

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, iot

I'll start off by apologizing if this has been asked and answered, but I've been researching this for a few days and either I'm not understanding what I'm reading or I'm trying to do something unique or not possible(guessing it's the former).

Currently what I have is a Raspberry Pi that has a webserver running and a web UI for controlling what's connected to it.  It has a slew of REST API's that can be accessed to perform various tasks.  I have a couple of these setup with static IP addresses and all works great.  My problem is scale.  The potential exists to have hundreds(to thousands) of these running and need to be controlled by a single mobile app.  I don't want to have thousands of static IP's.  Though this would be the easiest solution it certainly wouldn't be cost effective and most likely a nightmare to manage.

My desire is to "connect" all of these Raspberry Pi webservers to the Azure IoT hub.  The webservers do not need to talk to each other, but the mobile app needs to be able to send REST messages to each server individually.

The coding of the app, the coding on the Pi's and any additional coding is not an issue.  I've been an applications developer for over 20 years so coding is not an issue.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the minimum necessary to be running on the Pi to connect to the Azure IoT Hub?
2. Do I understand correctly that to do what I've described above, I have to send a message to the Hub and then the Hub sends a message to the device?
3. Does anything exist to define the Pi as an endpoint and just be able to send the REST messages directly to that?

Any help provided, even links to relevant documents, would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the official documentation? It contains an example of what you're trying to achieve (send data from device to iot hub / send command from iot hub to device)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d

All you need is the connection string to the Azure IOT Hub. To register your device, please visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks